# Python: How not NOT ADD to list comprehension in inline IF

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

How can I not add to the list in the else of an inline if?

For example:

```
somelist = somelist + (anotherlist if x==1 else ??)
```

in the ?? I want to NOT ADD anything without repeating **somelist**. I have tried **[None]** but that just adds a None entry to the list.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) are different things. The code you have there does not contain a list comprehension.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just doing `if x == 1:` followed by `somelist += anotherlist`? Why have an inline if at all?

Comment: that title though..☺ So much IT, much wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append an empty list.

```
somelist = somelist + (anotherlist if x==1 else [])
```

Comment: or `somelist.extend(anotherlist) if x==1 else None`

Comment: Yup, that does it! Thank you.